# Standard input in C++ with my loop

Tags: c++, iostream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   char c;
   cout << "enter the word.";
   cin >>  c;
   int count =0;

    while (c !='.') {
       if (c == 'b') count = count + 1;
       cin >> c;
   }

    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

When I compile the code, it accepts word but after that, does not calculate the count.

For example:

```
./d6
enter the wordbanana
```

Then I got nothing, and I add more words, why?

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](http://cpp.sh/823c) works fine for me. Are you confusing the output stream with the return code of your program?

Comment: Can you clarify "does not calculate the count"? What are the _exact_ inputs you're supplying and the _exact_ outputs you're getting and the _exact_ outputs you think you should be getting instead? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: it seems to work fine for me too. If you are executing that from windows (for example) maybe your program is closing too quickly for you to see? in that case try using System.pause()

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Why do you think the `return 0` is important in "calculating the count" ?

Comment: @SouravKanta not `getch()`, `cin.get()`

Comment: I am on UBuntu ,have compiled with gcc.

Comment: Yes, you are going into infinite loop for not entering '.' character

Comment: I have changed this,again I have infinite loop.

Comment: Yea,works fine with "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A logically correct alternative

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    size_t ans, dot = line.find_first_of('.');
    if (dot != string::npos)
        ans = count(line.begin(), line.begin() + dot, 'b');
    else
        ans = count(line.begin(), line.end(), 'b');
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
banana
```

**Output**

```
1
```

See http://ideone.com/j7b5x4 demo

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine.
Problem might be in your input string. If you input some string without `'.'` character at the end, your code will end up in an infinite loop. And it will not print `count` variable.

And `return 0` is placed in proper place.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to include a "." character in order to end the loop.
return 0; seems to be where is should be, unless you're not using standard C++.

Comment: gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)

Comment: Where should I add "."character?

Comment: Works fine with ".' at the end.

Comment: When your program outputs, "enter the word," you need to put the number of 'b' characters that you want the variable count to equal. Then, just put a '.' character in the command line, and the program should output the value of count.